# Codeigniter 4 Shield registration problem

Tags: codeigniter

I just added codeigniter 4 custom shield package to my project for login and registration. I would like to use the register form when i logged in my project, but the register not working. The data is not saved in the database. I don't want the new regidtered user will be logged in. Sorry for my english.

Enybody meet this problem?

Ok, I will try to detail my problem. I am working on a project that is a register of the IT assets of a small company. I am the admin in this project. I installed the shield and it works great. I would like to be able to register new users with a "Register new user" button when I enter the project. I don't want the user to register himself. In this case, the shield only works if no one is logged in to the project. If I am logged in as an admin, the registration does not work, because the registry wants to let the new user in. I hope you understand.

Comment: please explain this a bit better: *I would like to use the register form when i logged in my project, but the register not working*? how are you doing your setup? AND *I don't want the new registered user will be logged in*? what does that mean?

Comment: Ok, I will try to detail my problem. I am working on a project that is a register of the IT assets of a small company. I am the admin in this project. I installed the shield and it works great. I would like to be able to register new users with a "Register new user" button when I enter the project. I don't want the user to register himself. In this case, the shield only works if no one is logged in to the project. If I am logged in as an admin, the registration does not work, because the registry wants to let the new user in. I hope you understand.

Comment: I'd make this much more simple: in your admin area, add user's email (to be used as username) and add it to a table approved_users. Send eventually an email to the user automatically. The new user then may take care of registering on their own, if their username (email) matches one in your table of approved_users. Advantage: less work programing as well as administrative for you. Users can handle their own passwords, improved privacy.

Comment: Thank you so much, this will be the solution.